# .net MVC 3 Request event

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a little new to .net and trying to grasp a few concepts.

I have been writing in Coldfusion for a while, and in CF there is an event under the Application.cfc called onRequest() that fires each time there is a page.

What in .net is used to capture the request information?

And moreover is there a way to latch on or extend the Request event to fire off my own events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want something like [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) which is called *before* the action is hit.

To access the current request you could do the following:

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
  //Do the default OnActionExecuting first.
  base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

  //The request variable will allow you to see information on the current request.
  var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpRequest;
}
```

If you want to access this in **every** controller, then you should probably create a base controller and add this there.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  //Code above
}
```

And in your Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
}
```

Comment: No, if you want it in every controller you should use a global action filter. Composition > inheritance.

Comment: @Ryan - Do you read anything other than Gang of Four?! I'd argue that global action filters are overkill in plenty of circumstances.

Comment: I'm just speaking from personal experience. My advice is to try things different ways to figure out what works for you.

Comment: not a good idea. mvc action filters and web api filters are inside separate namespaces. and with your method you should have two version of the code. one for mvc and one for web api... I preffer BeginRequest and EndRequest

Comment: This answer was written nearly five years ago and, like a lot of things, code can age badly with time. Would I do it differently now? Yes, I think I'd use a global action filter here because it's much cleaner? That said, I still use the simple basic inheritance controllers. As for Web API, that is out of scope here (remember: MVC 3). I won't change the answer however for reasons of posterity and instead invite you to put your own answer in.

Answer (score 6):

You can also find global.asax file and use one of events of `HttpApplication` class (for example `BeginRequest`):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx

`HttpApplication` has `Request` property.

You can catch every request there, not only related to Controller (images, css, wrong address).

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        //Request.Have_fun
    }    
}
```

If you don't want to write code in global.asax file, you should consider using `HttpModule`.

Create new class with this example code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += ApplicationBeginRequest;
            application.EndRequest += ApplicationEndRequest;
        }

        private void ApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something here with HttpContext.Current.Request
        }

        private static void ApplicationBeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something here with HttpContext.Current.Request
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Add two entries in web.config (registers HttpModule):

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyProject.MyHttpModule" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyProject.MyHttpModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webserver>
```

Because of changes in IIS7(adding system.webServer section), you have to add two entries in web.config.

Comment: LukLed would you mind elaborating a little on the HttpModule for me?

Comment: @jcreamer898: I've added some code for creating HttpModule. You can also find many tutorials in google.

Comment: This is a pretty heavy handed approach for MVC. In ASP.NET MVC, `OnActionExecuting` or action filters as the other answers suggest are better approaches.

Comment: @Matt Greer: I wrote about is as an alternative, which can catch also other types of requests (not only related to controller).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in ASP.NET MVC 3 I would recommend using global action filters (use one per "event" you want to handle) instead of tapping directly into the ASP.NET Application/Request stack.